# Can I add a Chrome extension in a build electron app from inspect element console?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, electron

I would like to know if I can use a chrome extension in an Electron app that it is not mine, I use it for work and I would like to get some content by document.querySelector() in order to improve my work.
I Am able to open devtools (chrome inspect tools) in electron app with ctrl+maiusc+i but trying some codes about loadExtension I found online but it doesn't work.

I tried from the original documentation session.defaultSession.loadExension but it doesn't work, it seems it doesn't exist session.defaultSession object in devtools console, I can get to loadextension method by session.remote.BrowserView.defaultSession.loadExtension